# Google Cloud Kubernetes pod / job history

Tags: cloud, kubernetes, google, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm looking for a way to see the events that happened in my GCK.
Is there a page on Google cloud to see all the pod / job launched today with theirs names and ids ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific page in GCP that shows historical view of pods/jobs launched today, for example. From (Kubernetes Engine --> Workloads) page, you can see everything (Job/Deployment/Stateful_Set/Replication_Controller) running, but no job IDs.